# DFA for a set {1,2,4,8,..,2^n} written in binary

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have to construct a minimal Deterministic Finite State Automaton(DFA) for a set :-

L = {1,2,2<sup>2</sup>,2<sup>3</sup>,2<sup>4</sup>....,2<sup>n</sup>} where numbers 1,2,2<sup>2</sup>,2<sup>3</sup>,2<sup>4</sup>....,2<sup>n</sup> written in binary and Input alphabet = {0,1} and 'n' is a non-negative integer.

I have constructed a minimal DFA as :-

[image]

Regular Expression(RegEx) for this DFA should be :- 10* because Language contains strings {1,10,100,1000,....}

Now, I am confused whether should I have to consider a unique representation for every string of the given set(Language) or not.
Here , string '1' has infinitely many representations like {1,01,001,0001,.....}
Similarly, I can get many representations for every string of the set by appending zeros initially.
So, If I consider it then I am getting RegEx as 0*10*.
According to this RegEx, my equivalent minimal DFA will be :-
[image]

So, My question is : which DFA is correct according to the given description of the set which I have written initially. Should I have to mention that all strings should be started with '1' or every string has unique representation for the precise description of the language so that I can get the unique minimal DFA for the given set.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second one because it is more flexible and if you have a situation where you need to store your number in a memory where memory field is bigger than your number(number of bits), you would need to add initial zeros to store it.

Comment: your statement makes sense. So, I should have to consider the second DFA according to the description of the language. Right ?

Comment: Yeah, I would do that.